# Damping and vector equation of planes

Tags: vector-spaces

Two completely different questions but I got stuck and wasn't sure on what to do for either. Any help?

Question 1: Three planes have equations:

Plane 1: x - 2y + z = 0

Plane 2: 3x - z = 4

Plane 3: x + y - z = k

a) Show that for all values of k, the planes do not intersect at a unique point.
b) Find the value of k for which the intersection of the three planes is a line and find the vector equation of this line.

Question 2: 
A particle P of mass m is attached to one end of a light horizontal string. The other end of the string is attached to a fixed point. The magnitude of the tension in the string is given by 2mxk^2, where x is the extension in the spring at time t seconds and k > 0 is a constant. The particle experiences a resistance to motion of magnitude 3kmv, where v is the speed of the particle after t seconds.

a) Show that d^2 x/dt^2 + 3k(dx/dt) + 2k^2x = 0.

b) Given that t = 0, x = 4 and v = -3k:

i) Find x in terms of t and k

ii) State whether the damping is light, heavy or critical.

The only part i'm sure about for either is that I'm fairly certain the damping is light in Q2 b ii)

But i'm especially stuck on the whole of question 1 and the first part of Q2

Any help appreciated

Comment: Hint for question 1: The first two planes intersect in a fixed line.

Comment: You really should split these two problems into separate questions. They don’t have much, if anything, to do with each other.

Comment: For part (ii), how did you come to be “fairly certain” that the damping is light (by which I assume you mean the more common term _underdamped_)?

Comment: Hi sorry I meant the damping is heavy

Comment: Also I get that they intersect in a line but how do I prove that?

Comment: They’re not parallel, so what else _can_ the intersection be but a line? This is a basic geometric fact. Algebraically, the coefficient matrix of the system of two equations has full rank, so its nullity is one—the solution space is one-dimensional.

Comment: They form a triangular prism, or a sheaf right? And I understand that they form a sheaf when the matrix of coefficients is singular and there is an infinite number of solutions, but how do I show for any value of k that there's no intersection? My only thinking would be to show that the matrix of coefficients is singular. But then I'd be unsure of what to do for the second part of the question

Comment: And after that I've got no clue on how to find the vector equation of the line

Comment: If the coefficient matrix is singular, then there is either no solution or an infinite number of them.

Comment: How do I differentiate between the two possibilities?

Comment: You’re asking about a lot of fundamentals of linear algebra. You’d do well to go back and review them.

Comment: I read my textbook but it was unclear